# React JS: HTML is rendered on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It must be an ultra basic. I want to make a very first demo, without using JSX to be more direct.

```
 const nicolas = {
    admin: true,
    id: 1,
    email: "xyz@zyx.io",
    name: "Nicolas",
    statement: "Star Wars rocks"
};

class User extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement('div', null,
                `<div>name: ${this.props.name}</div>
                <div>statement: ${this.props.statement}</div>`
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(User, nicolas, null),
        document.querySelector('section.app')
);
```

As a result, `div` tags are shown directly. Why ? and how to avoid that ? Must I use multiple imbricated `React.createElement()`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ?

Because you are passing a string as a child to the element. The string is literally rendered into the document. It's the same as if you did:

```
<div>{'<span>something</span>'}</div>
```

in JSX, which is *not* the same as

```
<div><span>something</span></div>
```

> How to avoid that ? Must I use multiple imbricated `React.createElement()`

Yes, every element needs to be created with `React.createElement`. [There is a way to directly set HTML as content of an element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but you should avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

`React.createElement(root, props, elements)` accept multiples elements, that can be strings.

```
const e = React.createElement;
class User extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return e('div', null,
            // strong for the whole line
            e('div', null,
                    e('strong', null, `name: ${this.props.name}`)
            ),
            // strong for left part only
            e('div', null,
                    e('strong', null, 'statement:'),
                    e('span', null, this.props.statement)
            )
    }
}
```

[React.createElement Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) ; 
[React Without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html)